# Regular expression extract a JavaScript variable in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, web-scraping

I have a large HTML file, containing a lot of content. I want to get a JavaScript variable, named `'a'` for example, from the whole file.

Example: (deleted lots of the actual content)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var a = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}];
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ....
    </body>
</html>
```

What should come from the above is:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
preg_match('#var a = (.*?);\s*$#m', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Explanation:

- Regex will try to match any line containing `var a =`
- It will then match everything up until a `;`, any amount of spaces `\s*`, then the end of the line `$`
- The `m` modifier will try to match each line independently, without it, the `$` would just match then end of the string which would be a bit useless

The *any amount of spaces* is only there in case you have some spaces after the definition, no other reason (e.g. human error). If you're sure that won't happen, you can remove `\s*`.

Note that this doesn't replace a full-blown parser. You will need to make modifications if `a` is defined over more than one line, if `a` is defined more than once (think about scope, you can have `var a` on a global scope, then `var a` within a function), etc.

Comment: I found a problem. If for example, one of the values contains '&', the match stops there.

Comment: `var a = "may also break with a semi-colon ; in the var's value";` - unlikely, but just adding as a note.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That works fine (notice the condition on the *end of the line*) - I just tested it.

Comment: Absolutely true, I stand corrected. +1 (it would also match the apostrophes in this case but as OP is looking for an array of objects instead of strings that shouldn't matter).