# Regular Expression to Extract Javascript Object from Scraped HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, web-scraping

I have a full page HTML scraped that have a lot of markup including HTML/CSS/JS code.

example below (stripped content)

```
<p>blah blah blah html</p>
<script type="text/javascript">window._userData ={"country_code": "PK", "language_code": "en",user:[{"user": {"username": "johndoe", "follows":12,"biography":"blah blah blah","feedback_score":99}}],"another_var":"another value"} </script>
<script> //multiple script tags can be here... </script>
<p>blah blah blah html</p>
```

Now I want to extract the object in `window._userData` and then if possible convert that extracted string into PHP object/array.

I have tried a few regular expressions found on SO but couldn't get it working.

I have also tried the similar answer here [Regular expression extract a JavaScript variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378690/regular-expression-extract-a-javascript-variable-in-php)

Thanks

Comment: the object you want to exract is incorrect.

Comment: @splash58 I have added the missing } , Thanks for comment, any solution please?

Comment: moreover, it cannot contain spaces and must have all keys in quotes - `{"country_code":"PK","language_code":"en","user":[{"user":{"username": "johndoe","follows":12,"biography":"blah blah blah","feedback_score":99}}],"another_var":"another value"}'

Comment: `/<script[^>]*>\s*window\._userData\s*=\s*([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/` and parse with json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find by regex

```
preg_match('/\bwindow\._userData\s*=(.+)(?=;|<\/script)/', $html, $m);
```

and decode

```
json_decode(trim($m[1]), true);
```

But before you should make correct json in that html.

Comment: This is the right anwer, but still you will have problems when the script tag contains more than one JS object and/or the object contains strings with `;`. If you can rule that out it will work.
edit: JS is not a regular language therefor [this answer applies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @JohannesStadler if json contains `;` or EOL,  its reallly a problem, i don't know how to solve

Comment: I think it's not possible with regex. Js is not a regular language so regex has its limits.

Comment: @JohannesStadler Yuo are right. Unfortunately, i don't know any library to parse js but js itself  :).